# how to fill by code nested tree structure into obj?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, tree

I would like to create a tree-like nested structure as obj (later JSON) but have struggling to do that properly.

I want to convert this:

```
root/app/index.html
```

into this:

```
{
  type: 'box',
  name: 'root'
  children: {
    type: 'box',
    name: 'app',
    children: {
      type: 'item',
      name: 'index.html'
    }
  }
}
```

How I can do that by code any advice?

Comment: Have you tried something ? A good place to start will be to split the path then you can reduce the resulting array to an object. Take a look at the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) functions.

Comment: yes, tried not to overload my question so don't put such simple stuff, my problem begins then I try do push() :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a recursive approach:

```js
let str = 'root/app/index.html';
console.log(convertToNestedTree(str))

function convertToNestedTree(str) {
    let members = str.split('/');

    if(members.length === 1) {
        return ({type:'item', name:str});
    }

    return ({type:'box', name:members[0], 
            children:convertToNestedTree(members.slice(1).join('/'))
           });
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, was tried via push and get into trobles then its update all names with a last one, but this one works just perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that takes string and `split` it into array and then you could use `reduce` method on that array to build nested structure.

```js
const string = 'root/app/index.html';

const parse = str => {
  const result = {}

  str.split('/').reduce((r, name, i, a) => {
    Object.assign(r, {name, type: a[i + 1] ? 'box' : 'item'})
    return a[i + 1] ? (r.children = {}) : r
  }, result)

  return result;
}

console.log(parse(string))
```

Comment: thanks to, but my embed javascript doesn't support assign :( but I got you